# Is there a CLI tool for keeping software dependencies up to date? (e.g. cli mode for renovate or dependabot)

Tags: dependencies, dependabot, renovate

How can I run renovate or dependabot via the CLI on a codebase to have it update the dependencies in the projects local files?

I'm looking to use one of these tools to run locally and pointed at a project on the file system. When finished, I expect the dependency versions to have been updated in place.

I'm looking to use them like `npm-check-updates` except not only for npm dependencies, but for any dependency.

It seems like renovate and dependabot are very tightly coupled to cloud platforms. That's great most of the time, but sometimes I'd like to use that functionality in isolation.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @rob I looked at other Stack Exchange sites and none seemed more appropriate for this kind of question. Where would you recommend I ask it instead? However, I think this question could easily be modified to comply by narrowing the question to ask if and how this is possible using renovate or dependabot since that's asking how to use a specific tool and not asking to recommend a tool. I've edited it as such.

Comment: The reason you couldn't find a more appropriate site is because it isn't allowed anywhere else, too. Your edited question borders on opinion and can only return a yes or no answer. Questions must be able to return a fact-based solution. [ask]

Comment: @rob The question can simply be reframed to be an open-ended question. I've re-edited it as such. However, there was never anything opinionated about it. It's a fact whether you can use these tools this way or not and someone can post an easily verifiable answer on how to use them as such.

Answer (score 0):

Renovate can be run locally, just use the Renovate Docker image for instance or the npm package.

Documentation: https://docs.renovatebot.com/examples/self-hosting/

Typically, using Docker/podman you would run:

```bash
docker run --rm \
  -v "/path/to/your/config.js:/usr/src/app/config.js" \
  renovate/renovate
```

Then, you have 2 options:

- running Renovate locally but configuring a Gitlab/GitHub repo to run against, this way you get the traditional Renovate experience.
- running Renovate against a local directory by using `-e RENOVATE_PLATFORM=local` (if using Docker) (https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/platform/local/) but you will have a degraded Renovate experience, not sure what it will do.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide more information on how to run it locally? Ideally with an example using docker including any contents for config files necessary. I was attempting to use `--platform=local` without luck.

Comment: You're right, didn't know that `local` platform existed. I updated a bit the answer but not sure of what local can give you anyway. Seems to be a dry run mode only.

Comment: hint local never worked for me more than a simple complain, maybe we have luck and find some nice answer here

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help someone to run Renovate locally (at least I was successfully running this on a Mac):

**Command to run Renovate locally:**

```
docker run \
--rm \
-e LOG_LEVEL="debug" \
-e RENOVATE_PLATFORM=local \
-v "/YOUR_USER_DIRECTORY/development/config.js:/usr/src/app/config.js" \
-v "/YOUR_USER_DIRECTORY/development/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY:/usr/src/app" \
renovate/renovate \
--dry-run=full
```

- Line 3: you can show even more log information by switching to "trace"
- Line 4: this one is important, it instructs Renovate to work on a local code directory instead of a repo
- Line 5: map your local Renovate config.js; it is quite basic (e.g. you are not allowed to define repositories, since in the local mode it simply checks the project in the current directory) -> see example below (of course you can place your config.js anywhere, the development folder under your user's home directory is just an example)
- Line 6: map your local project directory (must be the root of your project where you also placed the renovate.json) to the working directory of the Renovate Docker container (same here: you project can be anywhere; doesn't have to be under your user's home folder)
- Line 8: see https://docs.renovatebot.com/self-hosted-configuration/#dryrun for other options

**Example of config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  platform: 'local',
  onboardingConfig: {
    extends: ['config:recommended'],
  }
};
```

**Note: Limitations of local mode**

Running Renovate with the "local" platform is quite limited and its purpose seems to be manily for trying out configs/setups. Read https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/platform/local/ to get to know the limitations.

Comment: The config.js file and line 5 (mapping the config.js file to the container's config) can actually be omitted, since the Docker command already contains the local platform "switch".

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I suspect I must be doing something slightly wrong, but when I run this I get the following error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '')`. I tracked down the code from the stacktrace to [here](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/blob/main/lib/util/git/index.ts#L502), but I'm not sure I understand how `config` could be undefined here.

Comment: @ScottG Since I don't know what is in your config or know if you are even using a config, it's difficult to track down the problem. If you definded a config.js I would expect, that there is something wrong with it. In this case try to start the Docker container without your config.js. As I have pointed out in my comment, you don't need a config; you can remove the line `-v "/YOUR_USER_DIRECTORY/development/config.js:/usr/src/app/config.js"` entirely.

Comment: I tried many combinations including your exact config, no config (but with CLI flags set), etc. With no config and specifying `RENOVATE_PLATFORM=local` and `--dry-run=full` accordingly (and the 5th line removed) my combined config as logged is `"config": {"hostRules": [], "platform": "local", "dryRun": "full"}`. I can see in the trace output that it's finding files in my project, so something is working.

Comment: I noticed even if I don't specify dry-run, I still get this in my logs: `INFO: DRY-RUN: Would commit files to onboarding branch (repository=local)`. Looking at the [dry-run docs](https://docs.renovatebot.com/self-hosted-configuration/#dryrun) I tried specifying `--dry-run=null` and that log goes away. However, nothing seems to be changed in my repo and no matter what I still get that same error and an exit code of 1.

Comment: @ScottG Sorry, I misunderstood your message a bit and thought nothing is working at all. Anyway, maybe it's important to understand that the local mode is mainly to try out a config/setup (maybe look at https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/platform/local/ to see the limitations). As I understood (and experienced myself) you cannot use it fully on a local Git repo; you need a remote Git repo. E.g. it won't create branches on a local Git repo. I will add this to my answer to clarify...

Comment: @ScottG Maybe I can give you a little hint for solving the problem with the "Cannot read properties" error. First make sure, that the mapped project directory is really the root of your project (where the .git directory is). Then add a renovate.json file in the root directory of your project (I assume the error is caused by this missing file). Unfortunatelly I cannot assist you in what the content should be, but maybe you find some hints here: https://docs.renovatebot.com/presets-default/ -> Full Config Presets